# Copy folder from Android app to local Windows directory

Tags: android, shell, copy, adb

I'm trying to use the `Android Adb Command Prompt` to copy a folder inside the app container to a local Windows folder. The device is running Android 5.1.1 and is **not rooted**.

`adb pull` or `cp` aren't working. How can I copy a folder?

The following approaches aren't working:

**Approach 1**

```
adb shell
adb pull /data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs C:/temp/test
```

> error: device not found

Inside the shell you can't see to do `adb pull`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357066/426227).

**Approach 2**

DDMS can't access the `data` folder.

**Approach 3**

```
adb shell
run-as DroidSample.DroidSample
cp /files/MetroLog/MetroLogs/ C:/temp/test
```

> cp: /files/MetroLog/MetroLogs/: No such file or directory

**Approach 4**

```
adb shell
run-as DroidSample.DroidSample
cp /data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs/ C:/temp/test
```

> cp: /data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs is a directory (not copied).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876731/426227) is also not working.

**Approach 5**

```
adb shell
run-as DroidSample.DroidSample
chmod 777 /files/MetroLog/MetroLogs
exit
exit
adb pull /data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs C:/temp/test
adb shell run-as DroidSample.DroidSample
chmod 700 /files/MetroLog/Metrologs
```

> remote object '/data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs' does not exist

So also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472135/426227) isn't working.

**Approach 6**

```
adb shell
mkdir /sdcard/tmp
cp /data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs /sdcard/tmp
```

> cp: /data/data/DroidSample.DroidSample/files/MetroLog/MetroLogs: Permission denied

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8650449/426227) is also not working.

**Approach 7**

The only thing which half work is this

```
adb exec-out run-as DroidSample.DroidSample cat "files/MetroLog/MetroLogs/Log - 20160509.log" > C:/temp/test/test.log
```

But here I don't get the original file and I also have to know the exact file name. Additionally, that I loose line breaks and I have to do this for each file. Not that what I want.

So I'm running out of ideas. How can I access the internal stored files and copy them over?

Comment: try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296713/how-send-data-throgh-wifi

Comment: There is a answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8650449/2449199 that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to gain read access to /data partition on actual android device. Such thing is not possible without root access, even if the app folder is yours. For the reason that permissions to read /data partition are not granted and cannot be granted, unless you're using an emulator. On emulator, which by default is with admin privileges for developer, you can access the data partition to read and write. On actual device you cannot. Not with adb, not with DDMS.

So basically speaking, anything that requires access to those files under /data is not going to work. Whether you sue cp command or pull command. The moment your kernel reads the beginning of your path which starts with /data/... it says: Oops, no can do.

Answer (score 4):

You have almost solved the problem. As the storage of this kind is secured, you need to do one additional step. You need to copy the file from secured location to sdcard of the device. And then you can copy it anywhere via usb or android pull. Here are the command sequence I executed successfully.

```
adb shell
run-as DroidSample.DroidSample
cd shared_prefs
cp  DroidSample.DroidSample_preferences.xml /sdcard/DroidSample.DroidSample_preferences.xml
exit
exit
adb pull /sdcard/DroidSample.DroidSample_preferences.xml C:/test/
```

That's it.

And I really appreciate the way you posted your question. Best of luck.

Comment: This should be marked as answer.. works on non-rooted phone as well ( worked with debug version of app though ). not with live app

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access **/data** folder of android device which is not accessible in **unrooted** device.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as) the question was explicitely of accessing files from `data` folder for **unrooted** devices. I was able to access a file from `data` folder with `adb exec-out run-as com.packagename cat source > destination`. Why does this work then?

Comment: It works on emulator. Not on actual device. It could never ever work on actual device. Neither you nor adb has read permissions for /data partition. View my answer.

Comment: Tried it on device again and it works. Perhaps it is because of Debug build?

Comment: May very well be but I doubt it. As of your original question, none of the methods you listed will work. No access to data partition can be granted to you.

Comment: @testing yes, it's because of debug build