# Using ADB Pull to transfer entire folders

Tags: android, adb, storage, data-recovery, internal-storage

I want to use 'abd pull' to transfer some folders from my android phone to my Computer.
I've done a lot of research online but there isn't much information about how to properly use this command.

1. I want to transfer entire folders(with their contents) and
   not just specific files. is that possible ?
2. If it is, I am not super familiar with the android data structures.
   How do I specify the location, more specifically where do I start ?
   (for example: \system\xx or maybe \storage\xx I really don't know
   how to format this) I am looking for folders and files in the
   Internal Storage

Thank you all !

All guides on google or youtube show how to transfer specific files and only do so from sd cards. I want to transfer entire folders from the internal storage

Edit:
Thanks for all the comments, I find no definite answer so I gave trial and error a go. adb pull worked fine but an entire new problem came up.

Comment: Did your research included these so questions - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050925/how-do-i-adb-pull-all-files-of-a-folder-present-in-sd-card], [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115274/copy-folder-from-android-app-to-local-windows-directory]? If so, which of the solutions did not work for you? Did you happen to try to pull files from a folder that requires root access?

Comment: `adb pull` works fine on directories. But please ignore the folder you see in your OS when the phone is connected via USB. Those paths shown via MTP have nothing to do with the Android file-system. Instead perform `adb shell` and check the file-system in this Linux shell yourself. There are the paths you need to use for `adb pull`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the location directory that is of interest to you is: /storage/emulated/0/(Folder name you want to copy)/

So if I wanted to copy all my photos over to my PC I would type:
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

yes I can answer your first question
I want to transfer entire folders(with their contents) and not just specific files. is that possible ?
Ans: Make sure to open CMD where you have downloaded your Android Platform Tools.
go to your android device and make sure you enable developer options and enable debugging mode and required settings to wirelessly transfer data through adb.

if you need help refer this article
https://www.thecustomdroid.com/adb-push-pull-commands/

After you have successfully connected to your port.
You can use the below command

Adb pull /storage/ (to your designated folder on your PC) -- follow this if you want to pull data from internal storage.
Adb pull /sdcard/ (to your designated folder on your PC) -- follow this if you want to pull data from SD-card.

Example-
C:\Users\Downloads\platform-tools_r34.0.1-windows\platform-tools>**adb pull /storage/** ***C:\User\Downloads\recovery***

Let me know if this helped.